# How to setup Traefik as reverse proxy for ASP.NET Core app with kestrel?

Tags: asp.net-core, traefik

So long ago I started studying the data of the solution, but I am so stupid that I have not found a solution to how to configure file docker-compose for a simple ASP.NET Core for traefik proxy.

I took an example of a simple ASP.NET Core application from the Microsoft site, which, after deployment, is available at `localhost:8443` using `https`, because earlier I released a self-signed (`aspnetapp.pfx`), ok.

Then I unfolded the traefik and configured the dashboard I see that traefik gets information about the `aspnet_demo` container, but at web app addresses, or `webapp.mydomen.com/` or `localhost` nothing is available - maximum I get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in browser.

In logs traefik when referring to `webapp.mydomen.com` I get "RequestURI ": "/ "

What did you forget to point out?

I understand that the content `aspnet_demo` get on 443 port, so I tell Traefik where to look, but nothing...

Help me please understanding this. Thank you

My docker compose ASP.NET Core app looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"  
services:   
  aspnet_demo:     
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
    container_name: aspnet_sample     
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    networks: 
      - traefik-reverse-proxy
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.aspnet.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.aspnet.rule=Host(`webapp`)
      - traefik.http.routers.aspnet_secure.entrypoints=web-secure
      - traefik.http.routers.aspnet_secure.rule=Host(`webapp.mydomen.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.aspnet_secure.tls=true
      - traefik.http.services.aspnet.loadbalancer.server.port=443

networks:
  traefik-reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

My docker compose Traefik looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - traefik-reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./configuration/dynamic.yaml:/traefik_conf/dynamic.yaml"
      - "./configuration/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro"
      - "./cert/:/traefik_conf/cert/"
    labels: 
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefiklocal.mydomen.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=tls"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=unixhost:$$apr1$$vqyMX723$$6nZ1lC3/2JN6QJyeEhJB8/"      
   
networks:
  traefik-reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

My static config Traefik looks like this:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

log:
  level: DEBUG

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
    forwardedHeaders:
      insecure: true
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure
  web-secure:
    address: ":443"

providers:   
  docker:
    watch: true
    exposedbydefault: false 
  file:
    directory: /traefik_conf/
    watch: true
    filename: dynamic.yaml
```

My dynamic config Traefik:

```
tls:
  certificates:
      # first certificate
    - certFile: "/traefik_conf/cert/pem_com_2022.pem"
      keyfile: "/traefik_conf/cert/star_com_2022.key"
      # second certificate
    - certFile: "/traefik_conf/cert/aspnetapp.pem"
      keyfile: "/traefik_conf/cert/aspnetapp.key"
      stores:
        - default
```